# Import parent-child XML data to Sql Server Tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a XML like this:

```
    <StateTree>
      <State ID="01">
        <Name>State1</Name>
         <CityList>
          <City ID="01" Order="1" CityGroup="1" CityBuild="1" GeoLocation="X">
            <Name>City1</Name>
            <Group>1</Group>
             <AreaList>
              <Area ID="01" GeoLocation="6">
                <Name>Area1</Name>
              </Area>
              <Area ID="02" GeoLocation="6">
                <Name>Area2</Name>
              </Area>
            </AreaList>
          </City>
          <City ID="02" Order="3" CityGroup="2" CityBuild="4" GeoLocation="5">
            <Name>City2</Name>
            <Group>2</Group>
            <AreaList />
          </City>
        </CityList>
      </State>
     </StateTree>
```

and I want to convert it to tables like this:

State:

```
ID        Name
01        State1
---------------------------------------------------
```

City:

```
ID    Order   CityGroup   CityBuild   GeoLocation   Name       State1
01    1         1           1           X           City1       01
02    3         2           4           5           City2       01
---------------------------------------------------
```

AreaList:

```
ID        GeoLocation       Name        CityID
01          6               Area1        01
02          6               Area2        01
```

How I can do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to write this for every field and all the inserts, but the following SQL should point you in the right direction:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = 
'
<StateTree>
      <State ID="01">
        <Name>State1</Name>
         <CityList>
          <City ID="01" Order="1" CityGroup="1" CityBuild="1" GeoLocation="X">
            <Name>City1</Name>
            <Group>1</Group>
             <AreaList>
              <Area ID="01" GeoLocation="6">
                <Name>Area1</Name>
              </Area>
              <Area ID="02" GeoLocation="6">
                <Name>Area2</Name>
              </Area>
            </AreaList>
          </City>
          <City ID="02" Order="3" CityGroup="2" CityBuild="4" GeoLocation="5">
            <Name>City2</Name>
            <Group>2</Group>
            <AreaList />
          </City>
        </CityList>
      </State>
     </StateTree>

'

--Select States
select
    ID = s.value('@ID','varchar(10)'),
    Name = s.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)')
from 
    @xml.nodes('/StateTree/State') x(s)

--Select Cities
select
    ID = c.value('@ID','varchar(10)'),
    Name = c.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)'),
    StateID = c.value('../../@ID','varchar(10)')
from
    @xml.nodes('/StateTree/State/CityList/City') x(c)

--Select Areas
select
    ID = a.value('@ID','varchar(10)'),
    Name = a.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)'),
    CityID = a.value('../../@ID','varchar(10)')
from
    @xml.nodes('/StateTree/State/CityList/City/AreaList/Area') x(a)
```

Comment: Just by changing `s.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)')
` to `s.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(100)')`? This makes no different if I do it.